# UNIQUE Constraint PowerDesigner9

Tags: unique-constraint, powerdesigner

I am a beginner with PD.

I would like to know if it is possible to modelize the UNIQUE constraint in the models ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Create keys on the table.

Comment: Thanks. i tried to create key like is described in this link http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38058.1600/doc/html/rad1232020427280.html  but its not works

Answer (score 1):

So, i found the solution for my problem.

to create alternative key you need to follow what described in this link  infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/…

If you got in the preview Tab :

-- The preview is empty because of the setting.
-- Check the generation option.

If you've just generated a script for a table, your preview pane will not show any content .
So, you need to go into: 
•   The 'Database' menu. 
•   There go to the 'Generate database...' item.
•   Click on the 'Keys & Indexes' tab and make sure that in the left tree pane the 'Create alternate ' and 'outside' are check-marked. 
•   Then save those settings by clicking 'Apply'. 
•   Then click 'Cancel' to close the Database Generation dialog. 
•   Next, if you do a preview on a table the content should be available again.

thanks all.